# PHP: htmlentities not working with variable

Tags: php, html, string, special-characters, html-entities

I'm using htmlentities() to convert characters like Ç and ® to its character codes. I'm getting the texts from the MYSQL database.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($array, MYSQL_NUM)){
  echo "<div style='float:left; margin-right:40px;'>
 <div style='width:148px; height:141px; background-image:url(uploads/".$row[0].")'>
   <img src='images/glasscase.png' alt=''/>
 </div>
 <font style='font-size:20px'>".htmlentities($row[1], ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8")."</font>
 <br/>
 <font style='font-size:14px'>".htmlentities($row[2], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")."</font>
</div>";
}
```

However $row[2] is returning an empty string when using htmlentities(). Does anyone knows what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the exact contents of `$row[2]`?

Comment: what is encoding of returned data? I mean what is *actual* encoding, not supposed one

Comment: How do you know? And why to use htmlentities at all?

Comment: Because the data is retrieved from a MYSQL database and I know the encoding from the fields. I have to use it because my customer will enter characters like ®ç˚ª•™¢.

Comment: utf-8 have them all. no need to encode anything

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you scrap 'htmlentities' and just use

```
htmlspecialchars();
```